# Javascript - Cannot instantiate multiple instances of the same object

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to instantiate multiple instances of the same object. The first instantiation works fine, but when I try to initialize another object, I get this error,

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<draw> has no method 'width'`

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Odyss3us/GB4JM/), and here is my code:

```
function halo() {
  var width = 720, // default width
      height = 80; // default height

  function draw() {
    // main code
    console.log("MAIN");
  }

  draw.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return draw;
  };

  draw.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return draw;
  };

  return draw;
}

var halo = new halo();
halo.width(500);

var halo2 = new halo();
halo2.width(300);
```

In summary, my objective is to instantiate multiple instances of the same "class".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are redefining `halo` cunstructor:

```
var halo = new halo(); // <-- change variable name to halo1
halo.width(500);

var halo2 = new halo();
halo2.width(300);
```

Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/GB4JM/1/

Comment: Shouldn't that be `return new draw` at the bottom of `halo`?

Comment: No in this case, it's not what we need. `return draw` is just the same as if it were `return {width: function() {}, height: function() {}}`.

Comment: Gaaahhh! Of course. Thanks, don't know how I missed that. Javascript OOP takes some getting used to.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest something structured a little more like this:

```
Halo = (function() {
  function Halo(width, height) {
    this.width = width || 720; // Default width
    this.height = height || 80; // Default height
  }

  Halo.prototype = {
    draw: function() {
      // Do something with this.width and this.height
    }
  };

  return Halo;
})();

var halo = new Halo(500, 100);
halo.draw();

var halo2 = new Halo(300, 100);
halo2.draw();
```

Comment: Why do you say that? What would be the benefits of doing it this way as opposed to the way I am doing it now?

Comment: @John, it's the standard way to do class-like-things.  It lets other people understand your code better, and allows it to be incorporated in other code more easily.  For example, if you later decide to have inheritance, this lets you work with existing frameworks, tutorials, and guides.  You don't need to do it, it's just generally preferred (and why I got confused about your code).

Comment: Ah ok, understood. Thank you for taking the time to explain that. You wouldn't know of any good learning resources on that topic, would you? I could just google, but there are quite a few articles out there, all stating that their method is the best, and it's tough to discern which "standard" to follow. :/