# C:\fakepath get jquery in IE not in firefox?

Tags: jquery, html

This is my file upload onchange event:

```
 <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" id="loadfile" />
```

This is the text field where I have to show the full path of the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function readURL(input) {
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            alert( input.value);
        }
        else {
             alert(input.value);
        }
}
```

This is the javascript which solve my problem. But in the alert value gives me IE7,IE8,IE9,IE10

```
C:\fakepath\test.csv
```

and Mozilla gives me:

```
test.csv
```

so how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The same kind of question is already been asked in SO . The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563435/javascript-cannot-instantiate-multiple-instances-of-the-same-object)

You can get full path in in IE only and don't have chance to get full path in Mozilla because of new security restrictions in browsers.

Hope IE too would hide the full path.

Comment: any way for access full path of file?

Comment: @JitendraMarathe No. That's the whole point of a security restriction.